# Mule Error : AsyncHttpClient has been closed while invoking the POST API

Tags: mule4

I have a mule application hosted on Cloudhub which invokes the same API say "example.com" in Parallel using **Scatter Gather** and **HTTP Request** component. 
The application is hosted on Cloudhub runtime 4.1.5. Everything looks working fine but we get intermittent exception message as:

```
HTTP POST on resource 'https://example.com:443/<path>/<res>' failed: AsyncHttpClient has been closed..
```

The part of stack trace is:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: AsyncHttpClient has been closed.
at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:121)
at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:505)
at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.client.GrizzlyHttpClient.sendAsync(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:364)
at com.mulesoft.service.http.impl.service.client.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.sendAsync(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:141)
at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequesterConnectionManager$ShareableHttpClient.sendAsync(HttpRequesterConnectionManager.java:104)
at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.client.HttpExtensionClient.send(HttpExtensionClient.java:72)
at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequester.doRequestWithRetry(HttpRequester.java:124)
at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequester.doRequest(HttpRequester.java:103)
at org.mule.extension.http.internal.request.HttpRequestOperations.request(HttpRequestOperations.java:131)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
```

Earlier this was an issue in Mule runtime 3.7.3 which they have corrected in later version of 3.x.x runtimes. Not sure if they have considered this correction in mule 4.x.x.

Comment: Which version of the HTTP connector are you using?

Comment: @aled The HTTP connector version is 1.5.5

Comment: @BalwantKumarSingh According to this article, it was a known issue in versions 1.5.6 and earlier, so maybe an upgrade would fix it: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Seeing-frequent-java-io-IOException-AsyncHttpClient-has-been-closed-errors-using-HTTP-connector-version-1-5-6-or-prior